# How to add a Text View to a regular View

Tags: android, view, shapes

I made a View and all it is is a solid color that is 30px high and width is set to the device width. How can I add a  text view on top of that view? I used Titanium for a while and it was simply:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView();
view.add(myText)
```

and that worked, but since I am doing this now in Java which I have only begun a couple days ago, I don't know how. Am I even right in using a View for a simple bar? Is their something else I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something of the sort:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context); //assuming you do this in a activity you can use "this" as context
tv.setText("Hello World!");
activity.setContentView(tv);
```

Cheers

Comment: Not sure I understand. This is what I got so far. I want to add welcomeText to target. `TextView welcomeText = new TextView(this);
welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + username);
View target = (View) findViewById(R.id.welcome);`
---------
`target.setContentView(welcomeText);` doesnt work

Comment: There's no need to create a separate `View` you only need to add your newly created `TextView` to the activity... For example, if you have:
    
    `public class A extends Activity { 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        TextView welcomeText = new TextView(this);
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + username);

        setContentView(welcomeText); //this sets your TextView as the view for your activity A
    }`

Comment: The purpose of the view is because its a little strip of gray that I want the text to sit on. It's like a header.

Comment: right, you can put a gray colored background to the TextView like `tv.setBackgroundColor(color);` but if you really want to use an additional view then you have to also add that view to the activity in order to have it show on the screen. therefore after `target.setContentView(welcomeText);` add the line `setContentView(target); //this will add the target View to your activity`

Comment: btw I just realized you cannot do View.setContentView(TextView), there's no such function. What does your `R.id.welcome` point to? What is your welcome View defined as in the xml?

Comment: ahh I didn't think of that. Setting the background color on the TextView worked.